# Сброс AI поля MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

С использование Hibernate необходимо написать класс с множеством методом по работе с БД, один из которых - очистка данных из таблицы, этот метод выполняется следующим образом:

```
@Override
public void cleanUsersTable() {

    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    try {

        session.createQuery("delete User " +
                        "where id>0")
                .executeUpdate();
        
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();

        System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN + "Таблица очищена!" + ANSI_RESET);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        transaction.rollback();

        System.out.println(ANSI_RED + "Таблица не очищена!" + ANSI_RESET);
        System.out.println("Because you have" + ANSI_RED + " EXCEPTION " + ANSI_RESET + e);
    }
}
```

Далее таблица в таблицу могут быть добавлены новые поля, но при добавлении новых полей Авто-Инкремент переменная начинает свой отсчет не с 1, а с той цифры, на которой стояла перед удалением данных из таблицы.

Собственно как я могу обнулить счетчик AI поля для того, чтобы после удаления данных из таблицы и последующем добавлении счетчик велся с единицы?

Comment: После очистки таблицы, вторым запросом обновить автоинкремент `ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = value;`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8923132/6752984

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, подробнее, ответ не понятен

Comment: пытаюсь реализовать запрос следующим образом:


`String update = "ALTER TABLE User" +
                    "id = 1";
            session.createQuery(update)
                            .executeUpdate();`

получаю ошибку
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ALTER near line 1, column 1 [ALTER TABLE Userid = 1]

Comment: вместо ID оставлял AUTO_INCREMENT, ошибка та же

Comment: изменил на 
`String update = "ALTER TABLE User AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
            session.createSQLQuery(update).addEntity(User.class);`

Ошибок нет, но АИ не обнуляется

Comment: Все должно работать (это native sql запрос), попробовал в песочнице, у меня обновляет значения http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/53b0fad/1 . Попробуйте сбросить автоинкремент в отдельной тразакции после удаления данных из таблицы.

Comment: Это очень странно, но выполнение запроса обнуления автоинкремента напрямую в SQL, а далее выполнение иных запросов через Java код дает нужный результат, а вот выполнение запроса обнуления автоинкремента через Java код и выполнение иных запросов через Java код  не обновляет автоинкремент.
При том проблемы с двумя транзакциями нет, реализовал в две разные транзакции - все так же, ошибки нет, как и обнуления

Comment: Странно, `session.createSQLQuery(update) .executeUpdate();` должно работать. Измените вопрос и добавьте пример кода, который выполняется, но не сбрасывает автоинкремент.

Comment: для очистки таблиц `truncate` используют обычно. он и данные быстро удалит и счетчик сбросит